# Mat to Bitmap converter - Argument Exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, opencv

I am using OpenCVSharp3 in a VB Net Forms application.  I have this working with C# but trying to convert to VB Net now.  I want to display the webcam feed to a picturebox.

```
     ''' <summary>
    ''' Feed from camera
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private _capture As VideoCapture

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Frame from camera
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private _frame As Mat

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Image
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private _image As Bitmap

     Private Sub CaptureCameraCallback()
        Try
            _isCameraRunning = True
            _frame = New Mat()
            _capture = New VideoCapture()
            _capture.Open(_cameraDevice)

            _capture.Read(_frame)

            If _frame IsNot Nothing Then
                While _isCameraRunning
                    _image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_frame)
                    captureFrame.Image = _image
                    _image = Nothing
                End While
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub CaptureCamera()
        _camera = New Thread(AddressOf CaptureCameraCallback)
        _camera.Start()
    End Sub
```

I have the above code to display the webcam feed to a picturebox.  But when I run it, I get the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

The exception occurs on line:

```
_image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_frame)
```

I think I need to dispose somewhere but not sure if that is the issue here.

**C# Code that is working -**

```
 // Declare required methods
    private void CaptureCamera()
    {
        camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
        camera.Start();
    }

    private void CaptureCameraCallback()
    {
        try
        {
            frame = new Mat();
            capture = new VideoCapture();
            capture.Open(CameraDevice);
            while (isCameraRunning)
            {
                capture.Read(frame);
                image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                captureFrame.Image = image;
                image = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No camera found on device", "Start Stream",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (streamBtn.InvokeRequired)
            {
                streamBtn.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { streamBtn.Text = "Start"; }));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Solution**

```
''' <summary>
    ''' Get feed from camera
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub CaptureCameraCallback()
        Me._isCameraRunning = True
        Me._frame = New Mat()
        Me._capture = New VideoCapture(_CAMERA_DEVICE)
        Me._capture.Open(_CAMERA_DEVICE)
        ' Enable button if there is a camera feed
        If _isCameraRunning Then
            Me.BeginInvoke(New SetButtonCallback(AddressOf SetButtonStatus), True)
        End If
        While (_isCameraRunning)
            Me._capture.Read(Me._frame)
            Me._image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(Me._frame)
            Me.captureFrame.BackgroundImage = Me._image
            Me._image = Nothing
        End While
    End Sub
```

Comment: How did the original C# code look like? Without seeing it, it is hard to detect any C#/VB conversion problem (if any).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Added the C# code now.

Comment: The VB code seems to be equivalent to the C# code except that you have left out the `Do While isCameraRunning` loop and the contents of the `Catch` clause. You have not shown the declaration of the variables (such as `_frame` and `_capture`), could the problem be there?

Comment: @blackwood I have updated the code now with a while loop and check if _frame is not empty.  When I debug, it goes into both the while loop and the check but still fails on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code ensures that the camera is running with

```
while (isCameraRunning) ...
```

If you don't want a loop, you should probably use an

```
If isCameraRunning Then
    _capture.Read(_frame)
    ...
End If
```

otherwise you might get invalid frames. Maybe it is also enough to test if there is a frame after having tried to read one

```
_capture.Read(_frame)
If _frame IsNot Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

If you still get the exception, do further tests to ensure the frame is valid:

```
_capture.Read(_frame)
If _frame IsNot Nothing AndAlso _frame.Width > 0 AndAlso _frame.Height > 0 Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: I have updated the code now with a while loop and check if to see if _frame is not empty.  When I debug, it goes into both the while loop and the check but still fails on the same line. Strange.